# Load the child form on the top of the control

Tags: c#, desktop-application

Hi all i have my main form as MDI form on this form i am having data grid view.  Now form selecting an option from file menu i am loading a child form and i set the property

```
      startposition=center
```

It is getting loaded but some part of the form is getting loaded below the data grid view how to over come this . A sample form is attached below [image]

Comment: "some part of the form is getting loaded below the data grid view" -- can you please elaborate on this?

Comment: If you observe the image the new form is not completely showing i owuld like to show the complete form

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by using this

```
               f.ShowDialog(this);
```